# NVDA reads logo as clickable when it isn't

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, nvda

I'm developing a website and NVDA is reading the logo as clickable even though clicking it does nothing. This is not desirable as it would be confusing for users.
After some poking around, it looks like this is to do with React, as the same behaviour happens on the site created during the React tutorial.
This happens on both `yarn start` and `yarn build`.

Steps to reproduce:
Install nodejs and npm

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Open http://localhost:3000 in Chrome

**Actual behavior:**
NVDA reads out "clickable banner landmark graphic logo"

**Expected behavior:**
Clickable should not be included

NVDA version 2020.4
Google Chrome version 91.0.4472.124
React version 17.0.2
Windows 10 Pro build 18363

Answer (score 0):

"Clickable" will be announced by NVDA if the element has a click handler **OR** if any ancestor element has a click handler.  You'll have to look up the chain of parent elements and see if "click" is being handled by one of them.  If there's a click handler on the `<body>`, then you're out of luck.  Everything will announce as clickable.